# php content preg_replace replace only special string

Tags: php

```
$content = file_get_contents('document.xml');
$limit = 5;
$element = '<w:pPr><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="18"/><w:szCs w:val="18"/></w:rPr></w:pPr>';
$replacement = '<w:pPr><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="18"/><w:szCs w:val="18"/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr><w:sz w:val="18"/><w:szCs w:val="18"/></w:rPr><w:t>text</w:t></w:r>';
$ptn = '/' . preg_quote($element,'/') . '/';
$content = preg_replace($ptn, $replacement, $content, $limit);
```

I have 24 matched results to replace. but how i can replace only 5 or 9 string? 
If i use $limit it replace first 5. not needed.
TNX FOR HELP.

Comment: it may help if you were to post the content of the document.xml file so we know what you are looking at. What results are you expecting? what have you tried?

Comment: @happymacarts i just want to replace 10th match not first 10 matches. I know that with preg_replace i can only replace all or 1 to 5(example)

Comment: You could use `preg_match_all()`

Comment: Pseduo code: get the strpos() the 9th one then do a str_replace (or preg_replace or other) starting at that index

Comment: It will be great if u can show example.

Comment: there are examples listed here http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php using Ivans

Comment: this maybe an answer for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907155/how-to-replace-a-nth-occurrence-in-a-string

Comment: @happymacarts how can i + rep u?

Comment: I think if you up vote my comments.