# PHP replace 2nd occurrence of word

Tags: php

I have sentence in my text file like below.

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy fox.

How do I replace the second occurrence of "fox" with some other word like "dog" in PHP.

The result should be

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

'How to replace a nth occurrence in a string', this question is for how to replace (for eg) 2nd character in a string but my question is replace 2nd word in a sentence.

Comment: do you know which work you will need to replace  or it is static example?

Comment: Maybe this post can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907155/how-to-replace-a-nth-occurrence-in-a-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a nth occurrence in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907155/how-to-replace-a-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

Comment: 'How to replace a nth occurrence in a string', this question is for how to replace (for eg) 2nd character in a string but my question is replace 2nd word in a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

this function help you to replace last occurrence

```
echo str_lreplace('fox','dog','The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy fox.');
function str_lreplace($search, $replace, $subject)
{
$pos = strrpos($subject, $search);

if($pos !== false)
{
    $subject = substr_replace($subject, $replace, $pos, strlen($search));
}

return $subject;
}
```