# Replace N occurence of string

Tags: twig

How do I replace only the Nth occurrence of a string in Twig variable?

Having `{{ content }}` with drupal Paragraphs in a template - how do I replace only the second or third or Nth occurrence of `</p>` in a paragraph.bundle with something else - for example `</p><div>...</div>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace a nth occurrence in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907155/how-to-replace-a-nth-occurrence-in-a-string)

Comment: Just extend twig with the function in the question above